# "no match for 'operator='" in c++, trying to make a linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I'm writing a C++ program using Code::Blocks.  I want to make a doubly linked list.

My plan is to make an node class called `geoPoint` with pointers `north` and `south` to other nodes.  I've written a test function to create and link two nodes, then traverse them with a third node.  Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class geoPoint
{
    public:
    geoPoint *north, *south;

    private:
    string description;

    public:
    void showDesc()
    {
        cout << description << endl;
    };
    void setDesc(string sourceText)
    {
        description=sourceText;
    };
    void setNorth(geoPoint sourcePoint)
    {
        north= &sourcePoint;
    }
    void setSouth(geoPoint sourcePoint)
    {
        south= &sourcePoint;
    }
};

int main()
{
    geoPoint testPoint,testPoint2,currentPoint;
    string sourceText("testPoint");
    string sourceText2("testPoint2");
    testPoint.setDesc(sourceText);
    testPoint2.setDesc(sourceText2);
    testPoint.setNorth(testPoint2);
    testPoint2.setSouth(testPoint);
    currentPoint=testPoint;
    currentPoint.showDesc();
    currentPoint= &currentPoint.north;
    currentPoint.showDesc();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
};
```

`main()` crashes when it gets to the line `currentPoint= &currentPoint.north;`.  The error message is:
`error: no match for 'operator=' in 'currentPoint = & currentPoint.geoPoint::north'`

I thought that `a=&b` is the right way to assign the dereferenced contents of pointer `b` to variable `a`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not `main` crashing; that's the compiler giving you a compilation error message.

Comment: As a side note; Instead of re-inventing the wheel, why not use `std::list`?

Comment: @bitmask, thanks for the heads up about std::list, i didn't know about that.  I'll need more than two directions, though; I'm trying to make a game where a room connects to other rooms via north, east, south, west.  I thought I should see if I can get north and south to work first.   Is there a built-in C++ data type that supports what I'm looking for?

Comment: Sounds like you want to implement a graph, so you could check out *the boost graph library* but that's probably overkill for what you need. However, an alternative solution would be to have many `std::list`s (perhaps even better `std::vector`s) that go horizontally and vertically and store the respective `iterator` in your `geoPoint`, which allows you to navigate with `++` and `--`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`currentPoint` is of type `geoPoint`. `&currentPoint.north` is of type `geoPoint**`. `&` is the *address-of* operator: you're taking the address of a `geoPoint*`, which stores the address of a `geoPoint`.

If you want `currentPoint` to hold a copy of the `geoPoint` to which `currentPoint.north` refers, use the *dereference* operator `*`, as in `*currentPoint.north`. However, if you merely want to refer to the object without copying it, change `currentPoint` to a `geoPoint*` and write this instead:

```
currentPoint = currentPoint->north;
```

Comment: That definitely fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: @sigil make sure you accept this as the answer by clicking the check box beside it if it answered your question.

Comment: @seth, i had to wait 6 minutes before SO would let me accept.

Comment: @sigil ok sorry, there's just too many people that will have their question answered but won't accept an answer as _the_ answer. I'll put you on my whitelist :)

Answer (score 2):

In the functions `setNorth` and `setSouth` you are taking the address of a *temporary object* (the parameter). This pointer will be invalid as soon as the function returns.

Comment: This isn't the reason for the error, but it is important, so +1.

Comment: @Roland-Illig, how do I take the address of the permanent object?

Comment: There are two ways: `void setNorth(geoPoint *newNorth) { this->north = newNorth; }`, which looks a bit like C code, but i nevertheless like that style. Or `void setNorth(geoPoint &newNorth) { this->north = &newNorth; }`. Both variants work, but in the latter variant the function call doesn't make it immediately visible in the code that the address of the argument is taken. It just looks like an ordinary call-by-value.

Answer (score 0):

Did you, by any chance, intented to write

```
currentPoint= *currentPoint.north;
```

?